# Transition item off screen on screen

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a div that I have `positioned: absolute;` and `left: -250px;`. When the open navbar button is clicked I want the item to slide onto page. I'm not sure what I am missing,

```
.drawer .drawer-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: -280px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-transition: left 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 1s linear;
    -o-transition: left 1s linear;
    transition: left 5s ease;
}
.open > .drawer .drawer-content {
    left: 0;
    webkit-transition: left 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 1s linear;
    -o-transition: left 1s linear;
    transition: left 5s ease;
}
```

When I click the navbar it opens but it does not slide onto the page.

Comment: Are you sure that the `.drawer` is a child of `.open`? Is the class `.open` being applied when the nav is clicked? Try to removed the `bottom: 0;` and `right: 0;` from the `.drawer` - you really only need (2), not all (4)

Comment: I am sure that it is a child. It does open, just the transition never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to apply the `transition` properties to the `.open > .drawer .drawer-content` code.

```
.open > .drawer .drawer-content {
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    left: 0;
}
```

You should consider optimizing your transition code to look more like the following:

```
 transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay];
```

So in your case it'd be:

```
transition: left 1s linear;
```

Finally, don't forget to use the browser prefixes:

```
-webkit-transition: left 1s linear;
-moz-transition: left 1s linear;
-o-transition: left 1s linear;
transition: left 1s linear;
```

Answer (score 0):

Css should look more like this:

```
.drawer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.drawer .drawer-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: -280px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 3s;
}
.open > .drawer .drawer-content {
    left: 0;
}
```

You dont need to set transition to .open ... .drawer-content. It should be only in mail declaration for this element.
Also you dont need overflow-y for .drawer-content. Maybe overflow-x for body is enough?:) 
I don't think taht it's proper to use different easing options on one element.
Cheers :).